# Pandas unable to select NaN rows after case when statement

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I just run this code to create another column through a conditional statement with the default value as NaN.

```
df['casewhen'] = np.select(
[
     (df['mfr'] == 'N')
    ,(df['mfr'] == 'Q')
], 
[
    'This is N'
    ,'This is Q'
], 
default= np.NaN )
```

After that I tried to select all rows with a NaN value but it does not return any rows

```
df[df['casewhen'].isna()]
```

Comment: That means all values in `mfr` column are either `N` or `Q`.

Comment: There's definitely other values in that column and the new column definitely has nan

Comment: df['casewhen'] = np.select(
[
     (df['original_data'] == 'N')
    ,(df['original_data'] == 'Q')
], 
[
    'This is N'
    ,'This is Q'
], 
default= pd.NA )